# Fetching object property after using $.makeArray() functionality from new Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have following code where I am using $.makeArray to convert my object to an array. Later, I wish to print or fetch the name and age of my object which is now in array:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var alpha = {name:"Ronald", age:29, gender:"male"};
var beta = $.makeArray(alpha);
alert (beta);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The output comes as [Object object]. Now, even if I am putting "beta[01][01]" to alert or console.log it is showing the error as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

Though, the makeArray function successfully converts the object to an array but, I am unable to fetch any results (eg: name or age of object which is now in 2d array).

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: It convers the object to an object array. `beta[01][01]` is the wrong method. use `beta[0].name`..and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in javascript if u alert an object, it will give you `[Object object]`. As this is an array you have to use index followed by the property name

```js
var alpha = {name:"Ronald", age:29, gender:"male"};
var beta = $.makeArray(alpha);
alert (beta[0].name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not a Problem...Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You actually alert **the array (object,object)**, and in next try you did alert the data **with wrong index** like [01][01] so it will throw undefined error.
You have to use like below [rowindex]['key']

Like below

```
 var alpha = {name:"Ronald", age:29, gender:"male"};
var beta = $.makeArray(alpha);
alert (beta[0]['name']);
```

[Document](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)